# How to change numeric values into text for custom range

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom range I have styled and modified.

For each step there is a value displayed underneath the range in a green box.

[image]

I would like to know, how can I display text instead of a numeric value for each point?

for value 1 : show everyone
for value 2: show my group only
for value 3: show only me

I dont know how to modify this javascript, so any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $(".range-slider"),
    range = $(".range-slider__range"),
    value = $(".range-slider__value");

  slider.each(function() {
    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this)
        .prev()
        .attr("value");
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on("input", function() {
      $(this)
        .next(value)
        .html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.range-slider {
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 40%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(100% - (73px));
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 66%;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

/*.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}*/

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>

<!--<ul class="range-labels">
  <li class="active selected">Everyone</li>
  <li>only me</li>
  <li>private</li>
</ul>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array with all your possible text and use it as below.

```js
var arr = new Array();
arr[1] = "show everyone";
arr[2] = "show my group only";
arr[3] = "show only me";

var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $(".range-slider"),
    range = $(".range-slider__range"),
    value = $(".range-slider__value");

  slider.each(function() {
    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this)
        .prev()
        .attr("value");
        $(this).html(arr[value]);
    });

    range.on("input", function() {
      $(this)
        .next(value)
        .html(arr[this.value]);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.range-slider {
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 40%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(100% - (73px));
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 66%;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

/*.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}*/

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>

<!--<ul class="range-labels">
  <li class="active selected">Everyone</li>
  <li>only me</li>
  <li>private</li>
</ul>-->
```

Comment: Great, Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $(".range-slider"),
    range = $(".range-slider__range"),
    value = $(".range-slider__value");

  slider.each(function() {
    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this)
        .prev()
        .attr("value");
      $(this).html("All");
    });

    range.on("input", function() {
    var str = "";
    if(this.value == 1)
    str = "All";
    else if(this.value == 2)
    str = "Group";
    else
    str = "Me";
      $(this)
        .next(value)
        .html(str);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.range-slider {
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 40%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(100% - (73px));
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 66%;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

/*.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}*/

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="1" min="1" max="3" step="1">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>

<!--<ul class="range-labels">
  <li class="active selected">Everyone</li>
  <li>only me</li>
  <li>private</li>
</ul>-->
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare variable

```
var abc = {1: 'show everyone', 2: 'show my group only', 3: 'show only me'};
```

and use like this to get the string

```
$(this).html(abc[value]);
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete will not work when user will use the slider.

Comment: @Jagjeet Singh this doesn't work. the text displays initially for the first step but changes to the numeric values when click the range...

Comment: That's work for me, You need to do changes in your javascript as mentioned in answer